# how to get contacts

Tags: blackberry, jde

How to get phone contacts in Blackberry jde and Open all images in a popup Screen select any one of the image from the popupScreen.

Comment: Not asking much are you?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply for my question.I got ideas to select file from gallery form the following 
http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_To_-_Create_a_File_Selection_Popup_Screen.html?nodeid=1498743&vernum=0 .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [BlackBerryPIM](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/pdap/BlackBerryPIM.html) class

Here is a tutorial on how to use the [PIM API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/pim/index.html)